# access open form where condition

Tags: ms-access, sqlanywhere, openform

how to properly write clause for a WHERE condition of Openform in Access 2016?

I made a datasheet form A and made double clicking field A of this datasheet return a form 1. I want to eventually put this datasheet in a navigation form with a few more control buttons.

So I put datasheet form A into a new form B. 
My WHERE condition as:
[field A]=Forms![form B]![form A]![field A]

## field A on the left hand side belongs to form 1.

Up until now, Field A still works fine.

But then after I directly move form B to a navigation form C, clicking field A didn't give me form 1. Because it's asking me to enter parameter, I think I messed up on the path that I gave to WHERE condition. I've tried: 
[field A]=Forms![form B]![form A]![field A]
and
[field A]=Forms![form C][form B]![form A]![field A]
It's doesn't work anymore.

What should I do?

Comment: If the code is behind [form A] and [field A] is on [form A], then why use Forms! pathing? Simply: `"[field A]=" & Me.[field A]`. If [field A] is text type, use apostrophe delimiters: `"[field A]='" & Me.[field A] & "'"`. Then it won't matter if the form is standalone or subform.

Comment: @June7 Thank you. But I forgot to mention that I was trying on macro, so access will ask me to enter parameter for "Me.[field A]". I think your method will work if I code this activity in vba. Will try this.